# Shiny: how to upload a .csv with header =T and separator ="," as default?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app in which I can upload a .csv file and then plot the data.

You could download the **[.csv file from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ye1ajss2ukn1e6/df_ts.csv?dl=0)**.

I did this using the code below

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel(
tags$h1(tags$strong("Shiny app"))),
tags$hr(),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  a("Example input file",
  href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ye1ajss2ukn1e6/df_ts.csv?dl=0"),
  fileInput("file","Upload the file"), 
  h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")), 
  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = TRUE),
  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE), br(),
  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', 
               choices = c(Comma=',' ,Semicolon=';'
                           ,Tab='\t', Space=''
               ), selected = ',')),
mainPanel(plotOutput("line") )))
server <- function(input,output){
data <- reactive({
file1 <- input$file
if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
read.csv(file1$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
})
output$line <- renderPlot({
if (is.null(data())) { return() }
df <- data()
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%d/%m/%Y") 
print(ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=param1)) + geom_line())
})  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My question is how can I modify this app so it is by default the `header` of the .csv file is `TRUE`and the `separator` is `comma` without the need to have all the radio buttons and options in the app above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could just do this

```
read.csv(file1$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',')
```

And do away with the radio buttons

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help :)